# Is it possible to compile 32 bit under a 64 bit Ubuntu?

Tags: architecture, compilation, x86, 64-bit

I'm using 64 bit Kubuntu, and I want to create a 32 bit version of my C program. Is this possible, or will I need to use a virtual machine?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using GCC? You can do it like this:

```
gcc -m32 -o somefile somecode.c
```

From [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compile-32bit-application-using-gcc-64-bit-linux.html), first result on Google ;)